# Inserting file name in first line of merged txt files

Tags: command-line, filename, paste

I want to combine multiple txt-files using the paste-command and I want the names of each txt file as a part of the newfile. The Txt-files (ie. 01.txt) look like this:

```
        X936    X937    X938
Y516    83      79      70
Y517    78      70      75
Y518    82      81      75
Y519    76      80      79
Y520    78      78      77
```

So at first I try to add the filename in the first line of every txt, like this

```
01.txt
        X936    X937    X938
Y516    83      79      70
Y517    78      70      75
Y518    82      81      75
Y519    76      80      79
Y520    78      78      77
```

but don't know howto do it. Later i want to combine all files in one table using

```
paste *.txt > newfile
```

like this

```
01.txt                          02.txt                             ....
        X936    X937    X938              X936      X937    X938   ....
Y516    83      79      70      Y516      83        79      70     ....
Y517    78      70      75      Y517      78        70      75     ....
Y518    82      81      75      Y518      82        81      75     ....
Y519    76      80      79      Y519      76        80      79     ....
Y520    78      78      77      Y520      78        78      77     ....
```

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/433866/create-header-to-table-from-the-output-of-the-command-paste

Comment: I suggest that you **edit** each of your multiple text files separately **before merging** them with `paste`. If, for example, you use TAB as separator between the columns, you should add the correct number of TABs after the file name in each file to make it get aligned correctly after merging. (This can be done manually, if only a few files, or automatically with a shellscript, if a lot of files.)

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way would probably be to have the operation in two steps, something like this (adjust the number of `\t`'s to your file):

`echo 0* | sed 's/ /\t\t\t\t/g' > header.txt | paste 0* > data.txt | cat header.txt data.txt > final.txt`

**Note:** I'm assuming all files start with 0... you might want to change that

Comment: that works perfect, merci!

Answer (score 0):

If "multiple" is not too many, you could

```
for i in *.txt ; do
    echo "$i" >>newfile
    cat "$i" >>newfile
done
```

Comment: works but not as i neetd. the data should be in new bu not the same columns

Comment: Please show an example of what you need - your description is unclear